# how to add new array in body.history.. nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i have Job history schema i want to push other data in History array..how do this..because its update my old Job history i want new one array add in Job history.

```
var JobChangeHistorySchema = new Schema({
      datetime: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      changetype: { type: String, default:''},         
      details: { type: String, default:''},
      updated_by: { type: String, default:''}
    });
 import JobHistory from './job_models/job_changehistory.model';

req.body.history = new JobHistory({ changetype: 'eesss', details: delta });
  ss.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id },  req.body , { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true, runValidators: true }).exec().then(function (Job)

"history" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58724445554a2515404de8ed"),
        "updated_by" : "",
        "details" : "",
        "changetype" : "eesss",
        "datetime" : ISODate("2017-01-08T13:53:09.319Z")
    },
```

Comment: Can you show us the `job_changehistory.model` schema?

Comment: edited please check

Answer (score 0):

for Add new array Use **Push**
Below Suggested Code

```
  var add= new JobHistory({ changetype: 'eesss', details: delta });

       req.body.history.push(add);
```