# how to remove {} empty field in array .. nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

i am using below code...but if Status is Empty iss show below result in database...i want to remove if Status is Empty ..

1 Address {}, Status {} save in database.

```
function CheckStatus(oldJob, newJob) {
  var obj = {};
  if(newJob && newJob.Status) { 
   obj.Status= {}; 
    if (oldJob.Status.total !== newJob.Status.total) {
      obj.Status.total = newJob.Status.total;
    }
    if (oldJob.Status.charge_description && oldJob.Status.charge_description !== newJob.Status.charge_description) {
      obj.Status.charge_description = newJob.Status.charge_description;
    }
  }
}
```

Mongodb

```
 "Job" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5873b352e7621d08fccc5890"),
        "updated_by" : "",
        "details" : "{\"current_status\":\"Completed\",\"address\":{},\"Status\":{}}",
        "changetype" : "Update",
        "datetime" : ISODate("2017-01-09T15:59:14.202Z")
    },
```

please help how what enter in If Condition ( below code not working)

```
 if(obj.address = '{}')
  {
   console.log('Empty');

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting an object's value to `undefined` essentially deletes them. You may use the `undefined` keyword easily as such:
`newJob.address = undefined;`

How i would check for an empty object and delete its content:

```
if(Object.keys(newJob.address).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object){
    newJob.address = undefined;
}
```

Solution is better explained in this question's answers:
[How do I test for an empty JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679915/how-do-i-test-for-an-empty-javascript-object)

Comment: i was change my code.. if(obj.address = 'undefined') not working

Comment: Did you read the question i referenced? I only answered the part of "deleting" a variable. Also, you should check for undefined without quotation marks. And you never make comparisons with a single equals sign.

Comment: if(obj.address == undefined) not working when i enter if(obj.address = undefined)  ..this working only empty ..

Comment: Thanks for answer ..its working  :) Your Good Man :)

Comment: i need one more answer..please see my old post..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533714/how-to-add-new-array-in-body-history-nodejs

Comment: I am sorry, i do not have experience with mongoose. Though i believe you have to change it in the schema itself.